# Download files from Extabit Server

Tags: downloading

I have a problem with downloading files from Extrabit server (Premium User)
I use Boat Browser hold on "Download" button and Share Link with AndroGET (Free) 
AndroGET start checking file and show filesize, but now always show 0 bytes
I didn't change anything in my phone / software and I must use Browser dowloader 
that is far slowe than AndroGET. Please let me know if someone knows how to download files from Extabit.

thanks